# How does: $p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}$ simplify to $\frac{p}{1-(1-p)}$

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to figure out how the geometric random variable can be simplified to the RHS, and would appreciate some help in figuring this out!

$p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}$ simplify to $\frac{p}{1-(1-p)}$

I thought it would be approached likeso:
$$p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}+p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}\implies p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{0-1}+p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{1-1} = \frac{p}{(1-p)}+p$$

Though I get the wrong answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n = \sum_{i=0}^n x^i$ for $|x| < 1$. Then $(1 - x)S_n = 1 - x^{n+1}$ and $lim_{{n\to\infty}}(1 - x)S_n = 1$, so $\lim_{{n\to\infty}}S_n = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

In this problem, your $x$ is $1-p$. When you substitute, $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{n-1}= \frac{1}{1 - (1-p)}$

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume that $\vert 1-p\vert <1$, then we have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty (1-p)^m = \frac{1}{1-(1-p)},$$
where I shifted the index $m=n-1$ and then used the usual formula for the geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

We take $p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}$ and by change of indices (just shifting) we can rewrite it as  $p\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n}$. This is just a geometric sum, whose sum is $p\frac{1}{1-(1-p)}$, and so we're done.